# Is there a way how can I disable listbox remembering last position?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone

I tried to find some property or method in ListBox which can set ListBox to top (first item would be first item in listbox). I mean that user tap on listbox and go to another page and when he goes back then he see list from first item. Is it possible? Because I can't find anything and when I tried set  but I didn't. I tried set ItemsSource to null and then again to previous content ListBox was in place where I clicked. Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I would hate it if the mail app any other apps zoomed back to the top after I already scrolled down

Answer (score 0):

The following code scrolls to the first item, when you navigate to the view:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var firstListBoxItem = listBox.Items.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstListBoxItem != null) listBox.ScrollIntoView(firstListBoxItem);
}
```

You may extend it by e.g. checking whether you are actually navigation backwards by using `if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) { ... }`

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't help. I debug it and I get first item in firstListBoxItem. I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use Updatelayout() property before  ScrollIntoView:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var firstListBoxItem = listBox.Items.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstListBoxItem != null)
     {
      listBox.UpdateLayout();
      listBox.ScrollIntoView(firstListBoxItem);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by:

Add an **`Loaded`** attribute in **`ListBox`** tag like,

```
<ListBox Background="WhiteSmoke" ItemsSource="{Binding files}" Name="listBox" SelectionChanged="listBoxClicked" Loaded="list_loaded">
```

And use its event handler like this code:

```
private void list_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox != null && listBox.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;    //To remove selection
        listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.Items[0]);    //To scroll at top (first) item position
    }
}
```

This should work. Let me know in case of any query. Thanks.